# What data type do I use for passing configuration arguments to a function in Python?

Tags: python

I tried using a dictionary.

```
myoptions = {}

myoptions["host"] = "localhost"
myoptions["user"] = "user"
myoptions["passwd"] = "password"
myoptions["db"] = "mynewdb2"

connection = MySQLdb.connect(myoptions)
```

Which returned this error.

```
TypeError: connect() argument 1 must be string, not dict
```

I'm trying to make the equivalent of

```
connect = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="user",passwd="password",db="mynewdb2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `**`:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(**myoptions)
```

That will map dict items to keyword arguments. Note that not all arguments are considered keyword, i.e. most C wrappers only accept positional arguments.